# Overloading DataTable methods in partial Dataset class

Tags: vb.net, class, dataset, partial-classes, generated-code

I have a Dataset with several partial class definitions in the Dataset.Designer.vb file. They are all partial class definitions, for example: Partial Public  Class ItemTable{}
The problem is that when I define the other partial class to extend the functionality, it has no access to the properties and functions that were defined in the original partial class.
The pictures below are of the first/original Partial class definition, and the one i created to extend it.... Why cant I access "Adapter"?
[image: Errors on Me.Adapter in extended partial Class]
[image: Works fine in original partial class definition]

Comment: Are you manually adding partial classes to a table adapter?  If so, why?

Comment: Where exactly would I add the partial class extending code? I tried creating it in its own file but seems like they arent pointing to the same class... When I try to use the overloaded method, I'm getting a "No overload that takes x parameters" error

Comment: I'll wager that you didn't put the partial class declaration in the same namespace as the existing class. If they're not in the same namespace then they're not the same class.

Comment: That, and another issue with class name confusion. I was making a partial DataTable class, instead of the actual TableAdapter.....
It is solved for now lol